# fivestar rating from a xml import field

Tags: 7, rating

I have used feeds xpath parser to import xml file and created nodes from that data.one of the items in the xml is star rating.Example  3 stars .Is it possible to give star rating based on this item.say for example fivestar widget has to show 3 stars in the above scenario.need help on how to go about this.thanks in advance.